# Legendre Symbol Question: Appropriately writing $(\frac{a}{p})$ when $a$ is not a square modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

If I show for all integers $x$ that $x^2 \not \equiv a$ (mod $p$), is that sufficient enough to state $(\frac{a}{p}) = -1$?

Comment: Yes.  This rules out both $(a/p)=1$ and $(a/p)=0$, and the Legendre symbol only takes three values.

Comment: That is the definition of the Legendre symbol. So, yes. But that is not the way one does that usually. One uses the Law of  Quadratic Reciprocity.